# Is mathjax library good for seo in 2021 as google is crawling javascript now

Tags: seo, google

I have a students site and have doubt regarding should I implement mathjax library or use images with alt text.

Comment: Do you expect people to be searching for the math equations themselves as opposed to the other text on the page?

Comment: I expect people to be searching text like Ohm law. But there is also possibility that people might try to search there quadratic equations like 2x^2+4x+x

Comment: for "ohm's law" it probably isn't going to matter which way you implement it.   That text is going to come from page titles and descriptive text around the formulas.   For specific quadratic equations, I'm not sure which approach would be better.  Hopefully somebody here will be able to give you an answer.